# May I have web site without index page

Tags: website

I need a website without index page.

This is a book-like site, and I just want something like this:

```
story_01.php  
story_02.php  
story_03.php 
...
```

Is there any downside or problem with this concept ?

Comment: Users have to know the specific page location or name. On the main page you can place something like book indexes and contents. By default web servers point to something like 'index.php'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, as @Ashtray said, that users need to know where to start. If you tell them to open `http://server/story_01.php`, everything will work fine.

But if they forget that and try to open `http://server/`, the web server needs to show *something*. If there is no 'index' file, some servers show a list of all files (which might be undesirable for security reasons), others show a "Forbidden" error message.

Note that the index file doesn't need to have a real index – it can just redirect to `story_01.php` without showing anything. In fact, most web servers let you change the name of the 'index' file from `index.html` to whatever is needed – it could be `default.html` or even `story_01.php`.

But, if it's a "book-like" site, then a list of chapters would be real nice to find there, wouldn't it?

Comment: Just be sure then the default.html file or whatever you would rename index.html to, is included in the default document's (landing page) list.